# is there a GUI client that can execute multiple queries and show its multiple results?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, client

I'm currently using pgadmin and it appears that it is not possible to send more than one query and retrieve multiple data sets back.

For example, if I try to do this:

```
select travelerId, name from travelers;

select dateCreated from carDealerships;
```

I would expect to see TWO sets in my data output window.  As you can see, these two queries have nothing to do with each other so I'm not trying to do anything fancy by using UNION or anything like that.

I really do want to see more than one result set in the data output.  In pgadmin, in the message pane, it shows that the first query result with XX rows from table "travlers" are discarded.  Then it says that the next set of XX rows from table "carDealerships" are retrieved.

Why does pgadmin discard the first query set?

More importantly, can anyone recommend a GUI client that can output multiple data sets based on the number of queries executed?  Doesn't matter if it's open source or proprietary.

Comment: The Postgres wiki lists several GUI clients. I'm pretty sure there is something that meets your needs: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Aqua Data Studio could be what I'm after.  To get multiple query results you have to separate your queries with a slash.  It's not automatic but it's a step in the right direction for me.

e.g.

```
select travelerId, name from travelers;
/
select dateCreated from carDealerships;
/
```